# Setting QScriptValue-local values prior to evaluating

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtscript

Is it possible, in Qt 4.8, from the C++ side, to set `QScriptValue`-local values in a `QScriptEngine`?

For example, let's say I have:

```
QScriptEngine engine;
engine.globalObject().setProperty("glob", 1000);

// ???: Set loc to, say, 42.
QScriptValue expr1 = engine.evaluate("glob + loc");
qDebug() << expr1.toNumber();

// ???: Set loc to, say, 99.
QScriptValue expr2 = engine.evaluate("glob + loc");
qDebug() << expr2.toNumber();
```

And I'd like the output of that to be:

```
1042
1099
```

The obvious solution to the contrived example above is to just make "loc" global and set + reset it accordingly, but for reasons that distract from this question that's not what I'm looking for. I'd like:

- "loc" to be local to each `QScriptValue`
- To not artificially modify the script strings by e.g. prepending `QString().sprintf("loc = %d;", 42)` or whatever to the scripts.
- To only use a single `QScriptEngine`.

The only thing I could really think of to try was:

```
QScriptValue expr1 = engine.evaluate("glob + loc");
expr1.setProperty("loc", 42);
qDebug() << expr1.toNumber();
```

But it seems the value is already fully evaluated by `evaluate()` and so `setProperty()` has no effect (no surprise there).

I also had a peek at [`QScriptProgram`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscriptprogram.html#QScriptProgram) hoping it provided a program-local environment but alas.

I *am* looking at the docs, and will continue to look at them after I post this, but this is the first time I'm using `QScriptEngine` and I have to admit my brain is turning to mush, so I apologize if it's right there and totally obvious. I will accept RTFM as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, at least I think this is the best way. The key is [`QScriptEngine#pushContext()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#pushContext) and `#popContext()`:

```
QScriptEngine engine;
engine.globalObject().setProperty("glob", 1000);

QScriptContext *local;

local = engine.pushContext();
local->activationObject().setProperty("loc", 42);    
QScriptValue expr1 = engine.evaluate("glob + loc");
engine.popContext();

qDebug() << expr1.toNumber();

local = engine.pushContext();
local->activationObject().setProperty("loc", 99);    
QScriptValue expr2 = engine.evaluate("glob + loc");
engine.popContext();

qDebug() << expr2.toNumber();
```

And as long as a given `QScriptContext` is active on the stack, all `QScriptValue` evaluations will use it. Pre-existing variables of the same name will be overridden by subsequent contexts.

The caveat I guess is you have to make *push → all evaluations → pop* atomic, rather than individual evaluations, if you're going for multiple threads and one engine. I wish there were a way to pass a context to `evaluate()`.